# Controller advice cannot catch exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, exception

I am relatively new to spring MVC and I am currently in need to include an authentication interceptor for the web services. I need the interceptor to throw an AccessForbiddenException if the authentication fails while returning true if it passes. I have also created an AuthenticationExceptionController to catch the exception and return a ResponseEntity with a HttpStatus. However, when i encountered internal error 500 and I suspect it is due to the AuthenticationExceptionController being unable to catch the exception. Below are my codes. Any advice on how i can solve it?

**AuthenticationInterceptor.java**

```
package path.controller;

public class AuthenticationInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) {
        // handle the authentication check 

        if(authentication fails) {
            throw new AccessForbiddenException("access forbidden");
        } 
        return true;
     }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex)
        throws Exception {
    }
}
```

**AccessForbiddenException.java**

```
package path.controller;

public class AccessForbiddenException extends RunTimeException{
    public AccessForbiddenException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

**AuthenticationExceptionController.java**

```
package path.controller;

@ControllerAdvice
public class AuthenticationExceptionController {    

    @ExceptionHandler(AccessForbiddenException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleException(AccessForbiddenException e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
    }
}
```

**root-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <bean id="contextApplicationContextProvider" class="path.context.provider.ApplicationContextProvider"></bean>

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="path.**" />
</beans>
```

**servlet-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" />

    <context:annotation-config />

    <annotation-driven />

    <view-controller path="" view-name="index.html" />

    <resources mapping="**" location="/" />

    <beans:bean 
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value="" />
    </beans:bean>

    <interceptors>
        <interceptor>
            <mapping path="/**" />
            <exclude-mapping path="/login"/>
            <exclude-mapping path="/authenticate"/>
            <beans:bean class="path.controller.AuthenticationInterceptor" />
        </interceptor>
    </interceptors>

    <context:component-scan base-package="path" use-default-filters="false">
        <context:include-filter expression="path.Controller" type="annotation" />
    </context:component-scan>
</beans:beans>
```

Comment: 1. If you're new, don't start with Spring XML; the world has moved on. 2. Post the 500 error. 3. Post the stacktrace, which there is one. 4. Post the request.

Answer (score 0):

@ControllerAdvice catches exceptions raised at controller level only.

So if the exception is thrown on auth level before the controller call it's futile.

Instead you can try to add a filter before auth and catch the exceptions in the filter.